# how to test rest controller contains multipart request

Tags: java, spring, rest

controller for rest api, for that testing i developed one test case using spring

but when iam trying to call it gives 500 error

please can any one tell me how to test?

How to call that rest api url from test case

rest api code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new-work-plan", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String newWorkPlan(
        @RequestBody WorkPlanEntity workplan, BindingResult result,
        @RequestParam("signature") MultipartFile file {

    System.out.println(workplan.getName());
    System.out.println(workplan.getLocation());
    System.out.println(file.isEmpty() + " " + file.getOriginalFilename() + " " + file.getSize());

    return "";
}
```

test rest api

```
WorkPlanEntity wpe = new WorkPlanEntity();
wpe.setName("chaithu");
wpe.setLocation("Hyd");

MultiValueMap<String, Object> image = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
image.add("file1", new FileSystemResource("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Lighthouse.jpg"));

ResponseEntity<String> response3 = rest.postForEntity(URI + "new-work-plan/", wpe, String.class,  parts);
    System.out.println(response3);
```

Comment: You want to test it? Or you want to fix it?

Comment: how to send request? @Raedwald if you know please tell me the way